# Pgfplots graphics tick label positioning issue with latex->dvi (but not with pdflatex->pdf)

Tags: pgfplots, dvi

I'm trying to plot an image file in a pdfplots axis. This is a minimal example (the files fig2a.eps and fig2a.png both contain the image that should be plotted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot graphics[xmin=-0.15, xmax=0.15, ymin=0.0, ymax=0.2] {fig2a};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When compiling with pdflatex, I get exactly what I want. With latex (producing a dvi file), the tick labels are all on top of each other inside the image, so something goes wrong with the positioning.

I suppose version information is useful in this case -- from the output to the screen I have this when running both latex and pdflatex:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the image, or else a link to it?

Comment: The images can be found here: [png version](http://folk.ntnu.no/josteinb/fig2a.png) and [eps version](http://folk.ntnu.no/josteinb/fig2a.eps). The png was generated by python/matplotlib, and converted to eps with imagemagick (`convert fig2a.png fig2a.eps`).

Comment: The dvi output is just an intermediate format; it cannot be viewed. I suppose that you looked at the resulting `.pdf` or `.ps`? If so, how did you convert the `.dvi` to `.pdf` (or `.ps`)? TikZ needs to know this so-called "driver" in order to produce a proper output dvi. Without the correct driver, the output will be screwed up.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Sorry, I didn't know this about the dvi output, so I was looking at that directly. After setting the \pgfsysdriver macro and converting the dvi to ps with dvips things look as they should. Feel free to post your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dvi output is just an intermediate format; it cannot be viewed.

I suppose that you looked at the resulting .pdf or .ps? If so, how did you convert the .dvi to .pdf (or .ps)? TikZ needs to know this so-called "driver" in order to produce a proper output dvi. Without the correct driver, the output will be screwed up.

Here is a brief list of the most common drivers:

```
% needed for latex; dvipdfm
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}

% needed for pdflatex and/or lualatex (it is detected by default)
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-pdftex.def}

% needed by latex; dvips (it is detected by default)
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvips.def}

% needed by latex; dvipdfmx
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def}

% needed by xelatex 
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-xetex.def}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % or \usepackage{tikz}; same thing.
```

If you use `latex; dvips` or `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, the driver is detected automatically. In all other cases, you'd need to write the correct driver statement.