# Drawing labels on Finite State Machines with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am trying to draw up some finite state machines with TikZ. However, when I compile the following code it puts my labels into the regular document rather than in the nodes. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
\draw [black] (15.6,-19.2) circle (3);
\draw (15.6,-19.2) node {$q_1$};
\draw [black] (15.6,-19.2) circle (2.4);
\draw [black] (33.9,-19.2) circle (3);
\draw (33.9,-19.2) node {$q_2$};
\draw [black] (17.49,-16.883) arc (132.7489:47.2511:10.695);
\fill [black] (32.01,-16.88) -- (31.76,-15.97) -- (31.08,-16.71);
\draw (24.75,-13.54) node [above] {$1$};
\draw [black] (7.9,-19.2) -- (12.6,-19.2);
\fill [black] (12.6,-19.2) -- (11.8,-18.7) -- (11.8,-19.7);
\draw [black] (14.277,-16.52) arc (234:-54:2.25);
\draw (15.6,-11.95) node [above] {$0$};
\fill [black] (16.92,-16.52) -- (17.8,-16.17) -- (16.99,-15.58);
\draw [black] (30.9,-19.2) -- (18.6,-19.2);
\fill [black] (18.6,-19.2) -- (19.4,-19.7) -- (19.4,-18.7);
\draw (24.75,-18.7) node [above] {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This is the output that I am getting from the above code.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Have you compiled to DVI? Try converting that to PS/PDF, or compiling directly to PDF with e.g. `pdflatex`. Edit: This is probably the same issue as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95666/, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of that. Compiling directly to PDF added the labels as expected. What does compiling to PDF change to correctly label everything?

Comment: See the questions I linked to in my edited comment above. Basically the DVI format doesn't handle the PostScript specials used to place the nodes (as I understand it).

Comment: Have you ever tried the `automata` library? It's quite easy to draw FSM with TikZ.

Comment: You should delete your [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20976721/914686) on [so] (to keep things clean).