# tikz driver dvipdfm for positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm following up [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95666/pgfplots-graphics-tick-label-positioning-issue-with-latex-dvi-but-not-with-pdf/225148?noredirect=1#comment529201_225148)
The provided answer doesn't work with me, Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{beamer}

\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,every node/.style={draw,minimum size=2.5cm,circle}]
\node [anchor=east] at (current page.east){};
\node [anchor=west] at (current page.west){};
\node [anchor=north] at (current page.north){};
\node [anchor=south] at (current page.south){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The circle are not well positioned, and even seems to shift at each latex pass due to "remember picture"...

Answer (score 2):

The positioning feature of pdfTeX needs to know the paper height and uses `\pdfpageheight` for this purpose. The `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` are usually not set if pdfTeX is used in PDF mode. The DVI format has no concept of a paper/page/media size. The driver `pgfsys-xetex.def` contains a workaround:

```
\ifx\paperheight\@undefined
\else
  \pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight\paperheight % this is to work around a positioning problem in xetex.
\fi
```

Setting this in the example of the question fixes the issue:

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{beamer}

\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def}
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  overlay,
  remember picture,
  every node/.style={draw, minimum size=2.5cm, circle}]
\node [anchor=east] at (current page.east){};
\node [anchor=west] at (current page.west){};
\node [anchor=north] at (current page.north){};
\node [anchor=south] at (current page.south){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file contains the stable position:

```
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{1864679}{10310646}
```

After two `latex` runs followed by `dvipdfmx`, the result is:

> [image: Result]