# Chemfig doesn't show bonds at all

Tags: chemfig

I tried using chemfig but I've run into a problem. For example I tried drawing a methane molecule with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}       % czech
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % unicode UTF-8
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{C(-[:0]H)(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
\end{document}
```

Instead of this

[image]

it only draws this

[image]

If I convert the DVI file to PDF it becomes this

[image]

I've gathered that it doesn't draw the bonds (duh!) and that it *might* be caused by me using the Czech babel thingie. I'm using LaTeX on Debian 9.

SOLVED: Instead of compiling by just `latex test.tex` I should have used `pdflatex test.tex`.

Comment: Works fine for me with pdflatex from texlive 2018. How do you compile and which version of texlive do you have?

Comment: @samcarter I'm using TeX Live 2016 (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17). I compile by just using _latex test.tex_.

Comment: Can you test if `pdflatex test.tex` works?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Maybe we could wait a bit before closing until some chemfig experts have a look. The docu explicitly states that compiling via the dvi route should work. So using pdflatex is just a workaround, the source of the problem might still be interesting.

Comment: @samcarter Ok, I retracted my vote to close

Comment: it works fine for me if I run latex, dvips then ps2pdf. @Tom how are you converting your dvi to pdf? chemfig documentation explicitly states the conversion route should be `tex -> dvi -> ps -> pdf`

Comment: if you want to use dvipdfm etc., you need to specify the appropriate driver to the pgf backend *before* loading any tikz/chemfig modules: see for example: [Pgfplots graphics tick label positioning issue with latex->dvi (but not with pdflatex->pdf)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96770/117534)

Comment: Another thing you may want to try out: add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{chemfig}`. It is unlikely to help but perhaps worth trying since `chemfig` is based on Ti*k*Z and you are using `\usepackage[czech]{babel}`.

Comment: @marmot If I add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` and compile it via `latex test.tex` it doesn't work. If I then convert the dvi file to pdf the way @Troy suggested, it works.

Comment: voting to close as dupe of the pgfplots question because the essential problem is OP not compiling in proper order and/or using the wrong driver for pgf when using `latex test.tex`, which is covered in the answer in the dupe question.